# A common word to group statistics method: count, mean, sum, min, max, median?

Tags: word-request

count, mean, sum, min, max, median are usually used in statistics.
Is there a common word to group them?

Comment: I think the usual word is "statistics."

Comment: As far as I know, the concepts of mean, median and mode are commonly called **measures of central tendency** in statistical sciences.

Comment: @Weather Vane The first impression of statistics, it is noun. Second feeling is a subject or university department .  Because I am not native speaker,  just wonder is it a word can make people think it is some measures/method to cope with data ?

Comment: If you look at the definition of **statistics** in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/statistics) it has both meanings. Someone might say "show me the statistics."